# Angular/Ionic http request ignoring https

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework, https

I'm trying to get an HTTP request from [locationiq.org](https://locationiq.org)

My code is as follows:

```
this.http.get('https://locationiq.org/v1/reverse.php?format=json&key=9753acbde443c3&lat=' + this.appWide.lat + '&lon=' + this.appWide.long)
```

However, the request isn't going to the https URL, but rather performing a non-secure request.  I know this since I get the error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'myurl' was loaded over HTTPS, but
>   requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
>   'http://locationiq.org/v1/reverse.php?format=json&key=9753acbde443c3&lat=31.76&lon=35.21371'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

How can I make sure that the request is on the https url?

Comment: maybe it redirects you to http, try to test it in browser and see if it change

Comment: @Hussein when I type the url in the browser without https, it redirects to http, but when I type it with https, it stays on https.

Comment: do ctrl+shift+i on chrome and open up network tab and make the request. You  will notice that request there and can check if its doing http or https.

Comment: @fastAsTortoise where do I see that there?

Comment: in the Network tab of your developer tools.

Comment: @fastAsTortoise seems it's https

Comment: Then its the issue on the service side. they have to enable https or you can also use proxy server to make this request work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Page you are calling at `myurl` has hardcoded http references like images `src="http://...` or stylesheets `href="http://` this is a problem of the **server site** and should be fixed there.